# drag a transform element cause a jump start on drag begin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to drag an image using jQuery UI.The problem is this when i drag image it will jump on start dragging.I google it and find out this is due to css `position` `Absolute` but not find any solution of this

this is the code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/99dXp/)

```
#currentimage img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dragable").draggable().css({
        "transform":" scale(2.79)",
        "opacity": "0.90",
        "left": "240px",
        "top": "79px"
    });
});
```

How can i drag a transform element with position Absolute without jump

Comment: Try position:relative.[Do you want this](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/99dXp/1/)

Comment: That seems because you are setting top and left to be fixed values set during each drag.

Comment: i must have to use `Absolute` position

Comment: Whats the problem with making it `relative`?

Comment: Take the transform off it I guess [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/99dXp/5/)

Comment: Why not make the wrapper div `#currentimage` absolute, instead of the `img` element itself? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99dXp/3/)

Comment: @ZINNED , By dragging in your fiddle i missed the image. I can't find it.It's invisible.

Comment: @user3168736 That's strange. Here it works fine. I just modified your Fiddle. All I did was taking away the `img` selector in your CSS, so that the absolute positioning is placed on the div instead of the img.

Comment: Sorry Zinned. Once again same issue occurs. Try irregular dragging. You'll miss the image.

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of the image in the CSS. And take the `transform` off `draggable`.

**jQuery**

```
$("#dragable").draggable()
    .css({
    "opacity": "0.90",
    "left": "240px",
    "top": "79px"
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#currentimage img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/99dXp/5/)